# Linq: determine if the number of items in a sequence meets a condition

Tags: c#, linq, count

What I'm trying to do, exactly, is determine if there is only a single element in an `IEnumerable` and then act on that. I **could** do a `.Count()` and a comparison against the result, but that is extremely inefficient.

Is there a more efficient way of asking an `IEnumerable` if the count of items it contains meets some threshold without using `.Count()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MyEnumerable.Take(2).Count() == 1 //to check if it has one element
```

Answer (score 6):

This would also take care of it:

```
if (seq.Skip(1).Any())
{
    // act on it
}
```

Comment: I like this. In my particular case I also need to use the first element so the Take version works better.

Comment: FWIW, +1. I think it's a bit neater than mine.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

[ElementAtOrDefault(index)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx) and comparing against `null` will work.

```
if (seq.ElementAtOrDefault(2) == null) 
{
    // act on it
}
```

Comment: Caveat emptor: this way of testing makes no distinction between a `null` value and no element.